# How to disable CodeRush for Roslyn

Tags: devexpress, roslyn, coderush

In the Roslyn version of CodeRush we seem to have lost the option to disable CodeRush via the DevExpress menu. Any idea how it can be done now? I don't want to uninstall it, just want to troubleshoot a very delayed right-click menu.

Comment: Is it possible to disable it like other extensions via: `Tools` -> `Extensions and Updates`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently your only option to completely disable CRR is what Josh describes in his comment.

- Tools -> Extensions and updates
- Locate and select 'CodeRush for Roslyn'
- Press the disable button

VS will remind you that this operation will require VS to restart in order to take effect.

Whilst this might seem awkward, it is in keeping with the standard and is the proper way to do these things. Anything else would be more like by-passing than disabling.

This technique will ensure that Studio does not load CRR in the first place and will categorically exonerate CRR of responsibility for any residual delay on your right click menu.

If you need any further help with CRR, please feel free to visit our support center. http://devexpress.com/sc